# Problems Injecting properties with Simple Injector on Web Api ActionFilters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

We recently switched from ninject to Simple Injector because ninject is really slow. I'm running into a serious problem when trying to inject Web Api ActionFilter properties during runtime. No matter what I have tried they are not resolved. I'm basing the code on the following docs [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/472187) and [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#ImportPropertySelectionBehavior) and [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20API%20Integration&referringTitle=Integration%20Guide). Please note that I've also tried registering my own IFilterProvider..

I'm creating my container like this:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new InjectAttributePropertySelectionBehavior();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

My attribute

```
public class InjectAttribute : Attribute { }
```

IPropertySelectionBehavior implementation

```
public class InjectAttributePropertySelectionBehavior : IPropertySelectionBehavior {
    public bool SelectProperty(Type serviceType, PropertyInfo property) {
        return property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectAttribute), true).Any();
    }
}
```

Sample code that I'm trying inject.

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    [Inject]
    public IMyRepository MyRepository { get; set; }
}
```

Has anyone else been able to inject properties on Web Api ActionFilters?

Comment: It's worth noting that my Web Api controllers are injected, but my authorization filters are not.

Comment: In your code example you create a new Container instance in the `container` variable, but you pass the `_container` field onto the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver`. Is this a typo, because otherwise it might be causing that bug.

Comment: Updated the code, it was because I was calling a method called CreateContainer and then stripped down the code for this thread :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce your issue by building a sample Web API project with the code in the articles you referenced, but it worked directly.

What I did was the following:

1. Create an empty Web API project in Visual Studio.
2. Added the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` from [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html) and registered (just as in your question).
3. Added the `SimpleInjectorActionFilterProvider` from [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/472187) **and registered it** as shown just below the code snippet in that article.
4. Added your `InjectAttributePropertySelectionBehavior` and registered it like in your example.
5. Added your `InjectAttribute`.
6. Added your `MyActionFilterAttribute` (and overwrite the `OnActionExecuting` method to be able to set a break point).
7. Added the `IMyRepository` and a `MyRepositoryImpl` class.
8. Registered the `MyRepositoryImpl` by its interface in the container.
9. I decorated one of my Action methods with the `MyActionFilterAttribute`.

After doing this and running the application by calling the action, I see visual studio breaking inside the OnActionExecuting method with the `MyRepository` property being set.

This is my configuration:

```cs
var container = new Container();
container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = 
    new InjectAttributePropertySelectionBehavior();

container.Register<IMyRepository, MyRepositoryImpl>();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Remove(typeof(IFilterProvider),
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders()
        .OfType<ActionDescriptorFilterProvider>().Single());

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(
    typeof(IFilterProvider),
    new SimpleInjectorActionFilterProvider(container));
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I'll break it down into a sample and put  it on github.

Comment: I need to narrow this down more.. I have a sample that passes and it's exactly how I have it in my main application but it's failing under that app when I run the unit tests. I'm wondering if it's because  ServicesContainer services = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services;
            //services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver().GetControllerTypes(services.GetAssembliesResolver()).Each(container.Register); can't be called from the tests